# Debugging IBM Watson APIs on Bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to use IBM Watson's conversation API on Bluemix and am getting the following exception. I am not able to find any documentation as to how to debug it.

```
Error:
 "conversation.py", line 14, in <module>
    response = conversation.message(workspace_id=workspace_id, message_input={'text': 'Will you be able to convert an html file?'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watson_developer_cloud/conversation_v1_experimental.py", line 45, in message
    json=data, accept_json=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watson_developer_cloud/watson_developer_cloud_service.py", line 263, in request
    raise WatsonException(error_message)
watson_developer_cloud.watson_developer_cloud_service.WatsonException: Error: NLU service error: Processing error, Code: 500
```

I checked the credentials and workspace id and they all seem fine. 
Any idea on how to debug will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming they're using standard HTTP codes, 500 means the problem is server side. Therefore you can't really debug it.

Comment: I was hoping that since I have created the service through bluemix, there might be some config settings which I have got wrong and hence the server side error.

Comment: So you're running the service yourself rather than just calling out to it? How did you spin it up?

Comment: I followed this the tutorial here https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/conversation/tutorial_basic.shtml
It is giving the same error on the tooling dashboard as well, so I guess the problem is not with the python sdk, but some config in the server

Comment: "Conversation" is an experimental service. It is not guaranteed to be always be working as expected.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty thanks a lot for that update. FYI i think it works for my use case far better than any other platforms. So would be interested to know when it becomes more stable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I don't want to leave it unanswered.

As @jonrsharpe said, `Error: NLU service error: Processing error, Code: 500` means that there was a server side error.

When you hit a 5XX error there is nothing you can't do more than trying the request again.